# Golang select wait on both a mutex lock and a channel

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex

In golang it is possible to use a `select` statement to wait on multiple channels at a time. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

(Lifted from https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/5)

Is there any mechanism to do something similar with a mutex lock, where you wait for either a channel or for a mutex lock to become available? Something like:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

func fibonacci(c chan int, mu sync.Mutex) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
        case mu.Lock():
            fmt.Println("locked")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    var mu sync.Mutex
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }
        mu.Lock()
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit, mu)
}
```

The actual use scenario is that I'm passing in a [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context) to a function that might be waiting on a mutex lock for a while, and I'd like to be able to abort the wait through the context.

Comment: A buffered channel with size 1 works well as a lock. To lock, send to the channel (blocks if it is already locked). To unlock, receive from the channel.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You called `Lock`, but there is no `Unlock` anywhere. It will result in a deadlock when you call `Lock` again on the mutex that nobody releases. If you really need to be notified about an event in another goroutine, use channel.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any mechanism to do something similar with a mutex lock, where you wait for either a channel or for a mutex lock to become available?

No.

You must redesign, e.g. by replacing the mutex with a channel based semaphore.